# Innocent-looking ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am struggling to show that the solution of

$$y'' (x) + b \exp(y) = 0$$

with initial conditions $y(0) = y_0$ and $y'(0) = 0$ is

$$y (x) - y_0 - \ln \cosh(x) \sqrt{2 b \exp(y_0)}$$

I have used the substitution $p = y'$ and got as far as getting

$$\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1 - \exp(y)}} = \pm \sqrt{2b} + \text{Constant}$$

Intergating and getting the constast seems to have me stumped. Can anyone halp, please.

This is evidently an example from Jaeger & Starfield - Applied Math book from years ago

Sorry guys, I am retired and struggle with Latex etc ! Regarding the last comment re' equality, this is what you have to do ,surely ? This solution will differ depending on the the choice of the constant of integration from the solution of p*dp = -b*exp(y)dy, surely

Comment: There's nothing innocent-looking about math not typeset in MathJax.

Comment: The last equality has to be fixed by the author (I admit this is the culprit).

Comment: The constant resulting from the integration is determined using the initial conditions you provided. And to anyone who edits the post - please look sharp! (where is the differential on the r.h.s.?)

Comment: (... the author included.)

Comment: Multiple the whole equation by $y’$ and recognize what $[(y’)^2]’$ is.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-2\tanh(x)\sqrt{\frac12be^{y_0}}$$ and

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-2\text{ sech}^2(x)\sqrt{\frac12be^{y_0}}.$$

Then

$$be^y=b\text{ sech}^{2\sqrt{\frac12be^{y_0}}}(x)$$ doesn't seem correct. Review the parenthesing.

Answer (score 0):

The equation you should get using $p=y'$ is $y' = \pm\sqrt{2b(e^{y_0} - e^y)}$. Ain't gonna elaborate it further.